# Responsive perfect squares inside a fixed positioned div. could anyone help me?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a fixed positioned div at the bottom of my web (oriented just for mobiles). Inside I have 5 links, and I would like these links to be perfect squares always but I want to avoid to use any fixed size so I'm trying always to use "%". These squares needs to be always distribute using the full width of the container.

html so simple:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="facebook">                    
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="info">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="contacto">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="telefono">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="galeria">
    </a>
</div>
```

and my css's so far:

```
.container {
    width:90%;        
    height:20%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:5%;
    left:5%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container a {
    width: 18.4%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;

}
.container a:last-child {margin-right: 0;}
```

Here you have the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jJsf/3/

So, could it be possible to make the links perfect squares whatever width or height the browser have?

or, if maybe my aproach is not good enough, any other way to make it?

note: I think I could do it probably using a square img inside every link but I would love to avoid the use of innecesary images.

thanks in advance and excuse my english, hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: The bottom answer on this page is very interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout. I tried it on your fiddle and it seems to keep everything square.

Comment: Ty Tim. very interesting aproachs there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already answered this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457076/1811992).
This solution uses a dummy div and `position: absolute;` to make responsive elements that keep their aspect ratio. This is a CSS solution.

To adapt it to your situation, you can do this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7jJsf/12/)**

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="dummy"></div> 
        <a href="#" class="facebook"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="dummy"></div> 
        <a href="#" class="info"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="dummy"></div> 
        <a href="#" class="contacto"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="dummy"></div> 
        <a href="#" class="telefono"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="dummy"></div> 
        <a href="#" class="galeria"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
    width:90%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:5%;
    left:5%;
}
.container .wrap {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right:1%;
    width: 18.4%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
.container .dummy {
    margin-top: 100%;
}

.container a {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
.container>div:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Very clever aproach. Good thinking. I think I may use your solution. thanks a lot

Comment: Do you think there's a way to do the same but this time the squares positioned from top to bottom at the left of the window?. I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/7jJsf/29/ but I can't make it work (perfect quares). I make another question about it (maybe I did wrong and should have use this question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759034/responsive-perfect-squares-inside-a-fixed-positioned-div-part-ii/22759898?noredirect=1#22759898

Comment: Done already. another kind user helped me with it with a bit of javascript. in case you interested here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jJsf/33/

Answer (score 1):

I would set the width and height to the viewport width (a percentage of the viewport width) like this:

```
width:16vw;
height:16vw;
```

[**Your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/7jJsf/13/)

Comment: Also a very nice answer. do you know if it would be supported on all mobiles (android, ios, baclberry, etc)?

Comment: Here is a full list of this approach across all browsers http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Comment: Pity it's still not very well supported. can't use it. but it looks to me like the future measure unit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this little trick

```
.container a {
    margin-right: 2%;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 18.4%;
    padding-bottom: 18.4%;
}
```

Comment: Ty, but your solution.. while it may work when decreasing the browser width or increasing browser high... it won't work when increasing browser width or decreasing browser height. thanks anyway