# Make table cells square

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-shapes, aspect-ratio

How to ensure that each cell of table should become **square** without using fixed sizes? And be **responsive** when they change width.

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
}
td {
  width: 30%;
}
tr {
  /** what should go here? **/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### New answer :

To **make the table cells square**, you can use the [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property on a `div` inside the `td` element. Like this :

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
}
td {
  width: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
}
td .content {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1 ;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

---

### Previous answer :

You can use the technique described in: [Grid of responsive squares](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457076/1811992).

Adapted to your usecase with a table and **square table cells**, it would look like this:

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
}
td {
  width: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
}
td:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
td .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="content">1</div></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

**[FIDDLE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/kQXkt/)**

Comment: Could both downvoters explain the reason pls I'm ok with that but it isn't very constructive without explanation.

Comment: this solution doesn't work on android <4.3 stock browsers. Still cool though :)

Comment: how to vertical-align:middle the content ?

Comment: @BradKent there is a technique described here :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20457076/1811992 (see 3.Centering the content). You can also have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css

Comment: Before align the text firstly you have to add " width: 100%; height: 100%;" to the "td .content {...}" and after you can align the text simple

Comment: If absolutely positioning `.content ` causes problems, then you can also use `float`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/vRLBY/1/

The key is to use:

```
td { width: 33%; padding-bottom: 33%; height: 0; }
td div { position: absolute }
```

because `padding-bottom` is defined in terms of the width. More information: http://absolide.tumblr.com/post/7317210512/full-css-fluid-squares

**Note:** Previously I posted a not working code (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vRLBY/)). Thanks to @web-tiki for reporting the bug ;-)

Comment: well this has a pretty wierd effect in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/cM3yb/

Comment: @web-tiki: For we it worked fine in fiddle. Can you describe the weired effect you are seeing?

Comment: Never used jFiddle before, so I cannot say when it looks okay and when weird... ;-) I would suggest, that you have to delete the ``body { ... }`` from the CSS....

Comment: well fiddle is very handy, you can edit it and save it to show us your technique working. It basicaly is like a webpage taht everyone can edit, save and share...

Comment: @tampis I just checked with firefox and it is better but the `td`s aren't square. I'll make a screenshot to show you.

Answer (score 1):

If someone's looking for a solution that does not require fixed `width` property (even in percentage), here's what I came up with based on above answers and the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457076/1811992) from approved answer:

```
td {
    height: 0;

    &:after, &:before {
        content: '';

        display: block;
        padding-bottom: calc(50% - 0.5em);
    }
}
```

It's kinda lame but it kills two birds with one stone:

- does the trick
- makes content aligned vertically

Comment: this is Sass/Less code rather than plain css

Answer (score -1):

```css
td {
    display: inline-block; <--- this is the secret
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.