# How to style table's content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create table dynamically:

```
function createResultsTable(data) {
    var table = $('<table id="tblResultsList">');
    var tr;
    var td;

    $.each(data.d.foundItems, function(i, item) {

        var button = $('<button/>', {
            text: item.code, 
            click: function () { CellClicked(item.x,item.y,"") }
        }); 
        i % 3 === 0 && (tr = $('<tr>').appendTo(table));

        tr.append('<td>').prepend(button).end();
    });

    $('#rstSearch').append(table);
}
```

Here how it looks in the view now:

[image]

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/14661/).

Here is the desired look of the content:

[image]

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxMJT/2682/).

But I am stuck. I don't know how to move to the center content and make it quadratic.

Comment: Did you notice that your buttons aren't in cells?

Comment: Actually they are in the same cell in each row

Comment: No, they are in the row without cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed your logic a little:

```
td = $('<td>').appendTo(tr)
button.appendTo(td);
```

and have added some styles. Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/14666/

If you want to make `td`s square, here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835903/6053654

Feel free to ask if anything isn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

That line is wrong:

```
tr.append('<td>').prepend(button).end();
```

What it actually does is append `'<td>'` and `button` to `tr`.
 That's because the return value of `append` is `tr`, not the new `td` tag. 
What you could do instead is:

```
$('<td>').append(button).appendTo(tr);
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be better to read more about handlebars. In this files you can read real html and load it dynamically. [This is the link](http://handlebarsjs.com/). You can install hadlebars with npm install handlebars.

Answer (score 2):

for arrange your content:

```
 var arr = [{"id":1,"name":"Mike"},{"id":2,"name":"Tom"},{"id":3,"name":"Herman"},{"id":4,"name":"Ursula"},{"id":5,"name":"Sam"},{"id":6,"name":"Jenny"},{"id":7,"name":"Helga"},{"id":8,"name":"Nikolas"},{"id":9,"name":"Surgen"},{"id":10,"name":"Jorg"}];

var table_str='<table id="tblResultsList" border="1"></table>';
$('#rstSearch').append(table_str);
var index=0;
var index_total=0;
var row_str='';
for(key in arr){
    index++;
    index_total++;
    if(index==1){
        row_str='<tr>';
    };
    row_str+='<td><input data-id="'+arr[key].id+'" class="my-btn" type="button" value="'+arr[key].name+'"></td>';
    if(index==4){
         row_str+='</tr>';
         index=0;
          $('#tblResultsList').append(row_str);
          row_str='';

     }
     if(arr.length==index_total){
          row_str+='</tr>';
          $('#tblResultsList').append(row_str);
     }
};
var btn_max_width = 0;
$('.my-btn').each(function(){
     var test_width=$(this).outerWidth(true);
     btn_max_width = Math.max(btn_max_width, test_width);
});
$('.my-btn').css({'width':btn_max_width, 'height':btn_max_width});


$('.my-btn').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
});
```

[like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqHVP.png)