# Table of fixed size with square cells and centered content

Tags: html, css

I'm try to build a table such that

- All cells have the same size and square shape.
- Cell size is independent from the cell content.
- Cell content is horizontally and vertically centered in the cell.

For example, see the following image

[image]

I edited the code found here [Make table cells square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835430/make-table-cells-square) to obtain an output similar to the previous image.

```css
body { font-size: 1.5em; }
table {
    width: 180px; /* fixed table width */
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    width: 33%; /* each cell has 1/3 of the total width */
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center; /* content is horizontally centered */
}
th { background: yellow; }
td:before, th:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30%; /* attempt to center the content vertically */
}
td:after, th:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100%; /* set the height of the cell */
}
td div, th div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
th div { color: red; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><div>+</div></th>
        <th><div>0</div></th>
        <th><div>1</div></th>
    </tr><tr>
        <th><div>0</div></th>
        <td><div>0</div></td>
        <td><div>1</div></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <th><div>1</div></th>
        <td><div>1</div></td>
        <td><div>10</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The result is quite similar to the previous image, but if the either the table `width` or the `font-size` are changed, then the vertical centering is messed up.

I think the only problem is the verical centering. As you can see from the code I made an attempt to center the content vertically by manually setting `margin-top: 30%`. But this value needs to be changed accordingly to the table `width` and the `font-size`.

Is it possible to automatically center the content vertically?

Comment: There's a [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property you can use on table cells... I would remove all of the positioning code in there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simplify the code. I've removed a lot the positioning code and other stuff in favor of simple table properties. I'm using [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) here so that it's easier to demonstrate changing the values, but you needn't use them if you need to support Internet Explorer, for instance.

I also added some code that increases the size of the table and its font when you click to show the centering works at a variety of sizes.

```js
var fontSize = '1.5';
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var css = fontSize === '1.5' ?
    '--table-size: 300px; --font-size: 4rem;' :
    '--table-size: 180px; --font-size: 1.5rem;';
  fontSize = fontSize === '1.5' ? '4' : '1.5';
  document.documentElement.style.cssText = css;
});
```

```css
:root {
  --table-size: 180px;
  --font-size: 1.5rem;
}

table {
  width: var(--table-size);
  height: var(--table-size);
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc(var(--table-size) / 3);
  max-width: calc(var(--table-size) / 3);
  max-height: calc(var(--table-size) / 3);
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  background: yellow;
}

th div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>+</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div>0</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div>1</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>0</div>
    </th>
    <td>
      <div>0</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>1</div>
    </th>
    <td>
      <div>1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>10</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code is simpler and clear to understand, thank you very much!

Comment: If I need to place several of these square tables in a single page but each table has different sizes, what is the best way to do it? The first thing that comes to mind, is to create a class for each table, such as `.table130`, `.table150`, etc. (where 130 and 150 are the sizes of the tables), but this seems a bad practice to me. How to do it properly? Thanks

Comment: p.s. I think it is better to remove `width: 180px` and `height: 180px` from the `table`, and add `height: calc(180px / 3)` to `td, th`

Comment: What do you think about the third comment?

Comment: Sorry, busy with paying work ;). I prefer naming classes more organically, so if there's a reason one table is smaller than another (it's less important, or it represents a different set of data), I'd use that information to name it. Even `table-sm`, `table-md`, etc. make more sense to me. That said, I'm in the minority in that opinion, and many developers use classes like `table130`, `pd-5`, etc., with no compunctions (you see this in Bootstrap's utility classes for instance). It's really up to you. I don't think it's a bad practice, just a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Use [css3 flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

table {
  width: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

th div,
td div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

th {
  background: yellow;
}

th div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>+</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div>0</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div>1</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>0</div>
    </th>
    <td>
      <div>0</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>1</div>
    </th>
    <td>
      <div>1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>10</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have square cells?

Comment: @soundwave just adjust the height property

Comment: Oh I see `height: calc(180px / 3);`