# How to make cells in table square

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried the solution suggest in [Make table cells square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835430/make-table-cells-square) and it didn't work, it made the cells take up almost an entire screen each. I also tried the solution in [Grid of responsive squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares/20457076#20457076) and it also didn't work.

Here is my code:

```js
var gridHTML = "<table>";
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  gridHTML = gridHTML + "<tr>";
  for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    let id = "cell" + i + j;
    gridHTML = gridHTML + "<td id=" + id + "><br></td>";
  }
  gridHTML = gridHTML + "</tr>";
}
gridHTML = gridHTML + "</table>";

$("#grid").html(gridHTML);

$("td").hover(function() {
  if (($(this).html() == "") || ($(this).html() == "<br>")) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightgrey");
  }
}, function() {
  if (($(this).html() == "") || ($(this).html() == "<br>")) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: larger;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="text-align: center; line-height: 200%">
  <div id="grid"></div><br>
</body>
```

There's a lot of junk in the style tag because I don't know what I'm doing. This code works perfectly to make a grid of square cells when viewed on my laptop but on my desktop the cells are rectangular.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that attempts to match the height and width of the table cells...