# Responsive diamond grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-shapes

I have a selection of squares (squares turned 45° to look like diamonds) which I want to use to make up a big **diamond shape** with a central red diamond.

I am having issues organising the diamonds themselves and the `href` seems to fail.

- How do I **position the responsive diamonds in a regular grid**?

Her is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/5Q8qE/):

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: #000000;
  font: 13px georgia, serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
#diamond {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
#diamond:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: white;
}
#diamond_red {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #AA1C08;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
#diamond_red:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #AA1C08;
}
```

```html
<a class="navigation">
  <center>
    <div id="diamond"></div>
    <div id="diamond"></div>
    <div id="diamond" href="/photos/"></div>
    <div id="diamond_red"></div>
    <div id="diamond" href="/projects/"></div>
    <div id="diamond"></div>
    <div id="diamond"></div>
    <div id="diamond" href="/archive/"></div>
  </center>
</a>
```

Comment: Post an image of how you want it to look..

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5Q8qE/3/) the effect you were trying to describe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The responsive grid of diamons:

I don't think you have the right aproach to achieve a **regular responsive diamond grid layout**. It would be much simpler to:

- create a [responsive grid of squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares) (3x3 or whatever grid you feel like)
- then rotate the grid 45 degrees.

That way you won't have to fiddle with borders, pseudo elements (`:after`, `:before`) and positioning each diamond.

Here is a [responsive example](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/5bGc9/)

[image: Responsive diamond grid layout]

It uses percentage width and padding-bottom to keep the **diamonds responsive** and `transform:rotate(45deg);` to rotate te whole grid and make it look like a diamond grid:

```css
body{background:#000;}
#big_diamond {
  width: 50%;
  margin:15% auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.diamond {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 31.33%;
  padding-bottom: 31.33%;
  margin: 1%;
  background: #fff;
  transition:background-color .4s;
}
.diamond a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
#red{background-color: #AA1C08;}
.diamond:hover, #red:hover{background-color:darkorange;}
```

```html
<div id="big_diamond">
  <div class="diamond"><a href="https://twitter.com/"></a></div>
  <div class="diamond"><a href="https://twitter.com/"></a></div>
  <div class="diamond"></div>
  <div class="diamond"></div>
  <div class="diamond" id="red"><a href="https://twitter.com/"></a></div>
  <div class="diamond"></div>
  <div class="diamond"></div>
  <div class="diamond"></div>
  <div class="diamond"></div>
</div>
```

*As other people have mentioned, there are some errors in your HTML that I corrected like: Ids need to be unique and href can't be used on divs.*

Comment: thanks very much @web-tiki. I can see the big diamond seems to determine where the elements sit if I'm correct? Played around with margin width to see this- reducing it tends to go left, caused by the float left. So lets say you want to increase the padding around each diamond - I assume you increase margin? but the forces the diamonds to go onto another level and be broken from the single consistent diamond, so how else do you deal with this change? sorry for all the questions, I really like to learn rather than copy code :)

Comment: @redrubia First, to understand better, you should remove the rotation (I commented the rotation code out so it doesn't apply in the following fiddle). Second, the big diamond contains all the small ones so changing it's marin/position will affect all of them together. That is why it is easier to deal with than to position each one seperatly. Third, in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/5bGc9/40/  I changed the padding between each small diamond. You have to be aware that when you change margin/padding or width on floated elements,

Comment: you need to calculate the sum of horizontal space taken by each element (width + padding + margin +border if there is some) and that must be = or smaller than 100% otherwise they can't fit and the last element goes to second line breaking your layout.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to be more specific / clear on your first question.

First of all, you are using the **ID** 'diamond' many times.  IDs are meant to be unique and used for one element.  You should be using classes for this, not IDs.

Second, you can't use `href` within div tags. You could wrap the divs in `a` tags like this:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/"><div class="diamond"></div></a>
```

Or, even better so that the whole shape is clickable you can put the `a` inside of the `div` and make the `a` a block level element that is 100% width and height like this:

`<div class="diamond"><a href="http://google.com"></a></div>`

```
div a{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kQj24/1/

Comment: the problem with wrapping the div inside the anchor is that the link won't be available on the exact shape; it's actually a little more complex to do (see my answer)...

Answer (score 0):

This html has fallback for browsers that don't support transform in that the diamond becomes a square. Also the `<div>` elements can be wrapped in `<a>` tags using this method without altering any existing css rules for `a`. If transform isn't supported the text inside the square class doesn't rotate either.

```
<center>
    <div class="diamond">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#"><div class="square"><p>Text</p></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="square"></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="square"><p>Text</p></div></a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">        
            <a href="#"><div class="square"><p>Text</p></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="square red"><p>Text</p></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="square"><p>Text</p></div></a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">        
            <a href="#"><div class="square"><p>More</p></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="square"></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="square"><p>Text</p></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

CSS, using your existing body rule:

```
.diamond {
    padding-top: 50px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.square {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
}

.square:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.square p {
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Q8qE/8/