# bootstrap different shaped images

Tags: image, css, twitter-bootstrap, image-gallery, css-shapes

I built this mock-up:

[image]

I was wondering if this type of gallery is possible to build with bootstrap, I did not start to code yet because I think that it will not work because of the rows.
I would like some second opinions, from people who have worked with bootstrap for longer than me.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26554491/3436942) for an idea as to how to achieve this.

Comment: Yep that's is similar to what I what to achieve,  just have to try to make it responsive, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Nunocruz Why, isn't the answer in the linked question responsive? It uses percent units .. and seems pretty much responsive to me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found something that actualy works!!**  and it's responsive! :D

[image]

```
.poligono, .poligono div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.poligono {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(10px);
}
.poligono .los1 {
    width: 355px;
    height: 355px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-74px);
}
.poligono .los1 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}

.poligono:hover img {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}



<div id="projects" class="projects">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-9 col-md-3">
                <h2>Projects</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                        <p class="descricao">Cenas maradas acontecem</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="poligono img-responsive">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="poligono img-responsive">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row margin-bottom">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="poligono">
                    <div class="los1">
                        <a href="#"><img class=" img-responsive" src="img/project_1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1 UNlogical"/> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if there is a default bootstrap for this the answer is no.
But yes this is possible with your own css.

I don't see why not you could not skew the image with something like the following:

```
img.tilted{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
}
```

If you want this "mask like behaviour" i don't see why you couldn't put all the images on a layer bellow and put a transparent image on the top

Or you can try to css clip it like this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/