# Responsive central square

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out the best way to do a central square of a body. I thought that it would be a good choice to use the viewport-length but I can't seem to get it my way. The code I have been using is just a "cheat code" and not what I am looking for. [image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="main">
</section>
</body>
</html>

body{

position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
background-color: #d0d2d1;
}

.main{

text-align: center;
width: 65vw;
height: 35vw;
background-color: #fff;
margin-top: 150px;
margin-left: 350px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about what you want to get? A "central square" is quite ambiguous. What size should this square be? Do you actually mean a square? Your example obviously uses a rectangle, not a square...

Comment: is this , this kind of things you look for ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NxzoqR

Comment: your code says 65vwX35vw , that's not  a square :) . to center this content, there is dozens of techniques display, position, transform, negative margins , etc .. actually the most efficient is display: flex,, then display:table works well if you want to include older browsers such as IE8 ...

Comment: margin: auto; "solves most of the problem like you are facing"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `vmin` unit to do a code a square. This unit represents 1% of viewport’s smaller dimension.

```
/* A square that will always fit in a screen */
main {
  width: 70vmin;
  height: 70vmin;
}
```

Now you should center it. The vertical centering is the hard part in CSS, a solution is to do it with a calculation:

```
/* 2D centering */
/* horizontaly: margin auto */
/* verticaly: the height of the screen - the height of the content / 2 (top & bottom margins) */ 
main {
  margin: calc((100vh - 70vmin) / 2) auto;
}
```

You can play with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/tzi/ndq3v09h/

Comment: if you used flex like i did, it centers itself no need of margins ;)

Comment: I love flex! I just tried to propose another solution ;)

Comment: playing with calc() is fun too ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-padding` to set a ratio to a box. It helps to draw a square or any rectangle that will be able to resize and preserve ratio in the mean time.

---

basicly with a pseudo element (floatting or inline-block) to draw a square

```
:before {
content:'';
padding-top:100%;/* equals width of tag */
float:left; /* or inline-block; */
}
```

Show & Run snippet below to see a square, a 16/9 and a 4/3 boxe.

```css
.ratio {
  display:inline-block;
  width:25%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:lightgray;
  }
body {
  text-align:center;
  }
.ratio:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
.b:before {
  padding-top:56.2%;
  }
.c:before {
  padding-top:75%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="ratio "> square</div>
<div class="ratio b"> 16/9 </div>
<div class="ratio c"> 4/3 </div>
```

adapt vertical padding for the ratio you look for.

---

i explained it here once [How to make a div's height proportional to its width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481292/how-to-make-a-divs-height-proportional-to-its-width/23481596#23481596)

---

you may use either flex or table to draw to center X,Y your square or rectangle

flex: [demo](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NxzoqR) based on [this template](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KVevEW)  using css below  :

```
html {
height:100%;
display:flex;
}
body {
margin:auto;
}
```

table: [example](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NxzoLa)

```
html {
display:table;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
body {
display:table;
vertical-align:middle;/* will set vertically content in center */
}
#wrapper {
width:xx; /* whatever you need */
margin:auto; /* horizontal centering*/
}
```