# Height the same as width

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using a block grid in Foundation:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-3 medium-block-grid-6">
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
</ul>
```

I want each li to have the same height as it's width. Each li has a different width at each of Foundation's breakpoints.

I've checked the web and looked into vw, the only decent solution I can think of is setting the vw height to be the same as Foundations li width at each break point.

Is there a better solution?

I do not want to use anything other than CSS.

Comment: You may also check this answer for a grid of squares : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/responsive-square-columns/20457076#20457076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative option in CSS to viewport units is to make use of `padding-bottom`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/dfn6Lvt9/)**

```css
div {
  width: 40%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: So I would just making padding bottom the same as the width at each breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.