# Responsive grid, equal height

Tags: css, grid, sass

How would i go about achieving this layout, in a responsive scenario (ie 25% width), but each block have the same height:

```
 _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|
|_|___|_|
|_|_|_|_|
```

Notice the middle block occupies (50% of the width), that middle block contains text, but the square images are images (that are square, giving its size).

Should i be using `display: table` mixed with `display: table-cell` and `display: table-row`? Or is there nifty css trick.

Comment: You might want to look into flex, a quite well supported layout in CSS3.

Comment: Nah duh, its a CSS3 concept. I'm more looking for something that is more browser supported. IE9+.

Comment: Sorry. It really is only IE9 that doesn't support it, though: [http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: you can check this question that is similar with a grid of responsive squares : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares/20457076#20457076

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is really cool but we are not yet at 100% for support, so I do not yet use it. I would probably check out something like www.shelvesgrid.org. Then have a width: 100% on the images within the boxes and if they are all perfectly square, it should work.

Your structure will look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column-3"></div>
    <div class="column-3"></div>
    <div class="column-3"></div>
    <div class="column-3"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column-3"></div>
    <div class="column-6"></div>
    <div class="column-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column-3"></div>
    <div class="column-3"></div>
    <div class="column-3"></div>
    <div class="column-3"></div>
</div>
```

An your CSS is just img {width: 100%}