# CSS <div> square

Tags: html, css

I'am new into basics of `HTML` and `CSS`.

1. Trying to create 3 x 3 square "picture", using , but can't find simple solution to put squares in the middle of the page, like nine square in center.
2. How to put all squares in the big bordered square?

How can we achieve this?

**HTML:**

```
<body>  
    <div class="square-one">
    </div>

    <div class="square-two">
    </div>

    <div class="square-three">
    </div>

    <div class="square-four">
    </div>

    <div class="square-five">
    </div>

    <div class="square-six">
    </div>

    <div class="square-seven">
    </div>

    <div class="square-eight">
    </div>

    <div class="square-nine">
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 150px;
}

div {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 275px;
    height: 275px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Try setting the body left and right margin properties to auto. This usually centres things. Apology if this is not right in your case. The div position and flow are important too but over my head. There are good tutorials out there.

Comment: Also consider wording your question more informatively. It is rather vague.

Comment: looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105579/responsive-grid-of-squares-within-a-responsive-grid-of-squares/37105929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [display: inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) `CSS` property. I think you wants to get the following layout.

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.square-holder {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
    width: 285px;
    font-size: 0;
}

.square {
    background: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 150px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="square-holder">
    <div class="square">
    </div>

    <div class="square">
    </div>

    <div class="square">
    </div>

    <div class="square">
    </div>

    <div class="square">
    </div>

    <div class="square">
    </div>

    <div class="square">
    </div>

    <div class="square">
    </div>

    <div class="square">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [text-align - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) with [display - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 150px;
  text-align: center /* add this */
}
div {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  /*float: left; */
  display: inline-block/* add this */
}
```

```html
<div class="square-one">
</div>

<div class="square-two">
</div>

<div class="square-three">
</div>

<div class="square-four">
</div>

<div class="square-five">
</div>

<div class="square-six">
</div>

<div class="square-seven">
</div>

<div class="square-eight">
</div>

<div class="square-nine">
</div>
```