# CSS: Why aren't these responsive squares totally square?

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

I'm trying to make a grid of resizable squares with some text inside them. Here's the code:

```css
/* Dirty quick CSS reset */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1;
  background: aliceblue;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
    
  width: 14.2857%; /* 100% / 7 */
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px;
  
  /* square-width - font-size - padding-top */
  padding-bottom: calc(14.2857% - 18px - 8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square">1</div>
    <div class="square">2</div>
    <div class="square">3</div>
    <div class="square">4</div>
    <div class="square">5</div>
    <div class="square">6</div>
    <div class="square">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As we can see, there's a row of squares that adapt to the size of the window. The problem is that if we inspect them, we see that they aren't totally squares (they are about 3px taller than wide). It gets worse if we increase the `font-size`, and as far as I know, the maths is correct.

What's going on here? Why am I getting those extra pixels?

Comment: I would expect it to be a rounding issue with the percentage based on the fact you say it gets worse as they get larger.

Comment: Adding `line-height: 1` helps but not perfect

Comment: I am not sure why yet but it seems to work at all sizes if you use `padding-bottom: calc(14.2857% - 18px - 10px);`

Comment: Add `line-height` equal to the font size, subtract the top and the bottom border from `padding-bottom`.

Comment: border makes sense why adding 2 more pixels to the subtraction fixes it, as far as I can tell you don't need line height though, works without it fine for me.

Comment: I tried adding the two pixels before, with different sizes but it doesn't always work. I tried specifying a bunch of decimals too, but it doesn't solve it. What drives me crazy is that I don't know why it happens.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` is defined for everything, so borders should of been included but apparently not

Comment: @amedina because there is rounding

Comment: If I change `box-sizing` to `content-box` happens the same.

Comment: @DrCord line-height is actually very important, because the height of the line is usually not equal to the font size. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nr2oyfaL/

Comment: @LGSon the duplicate provides good solution on how to obtain this but I don't think it provide the answer for the *why* here because it's important to understand the difference between the line-height and font-size [unless the OP only want the desired effect without explanation]

Comment: @TemaniAfif The _why_ is given in below answer :) ...and the dupe's provide many _how-to_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact calculation should be (`14.2857% - 8px - 2px - Lpx`) we remove the `padding-top` and the `border` and the `line-height` (not the `font-size`), so you should know the value of the `line-height` or you set it:

```css
/* Dirty quick CSS reset */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1;
  background: aliceblue;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
    
  width: 14.2857%; /* 100% / 7 */
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height:1em; /*equal to font-size*/
  padding: 8px;
  
  /* square-width - font-size - padding-top */
  padding-bottom: calc(14.2857% - 8px - 2px - 18px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square">1</div>
    <div class="square">2</div>
    <div class="square">3</div>
    <div class="square">4</div>
    <div class="square">5</div>
    <div class="square">6</div>
    <div class="square">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If we refer to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) the `line-height` is the value that define the height of the lines and the default value is set to `normal`:

> The line-height CSS property sets the amount of space used for lines,
>   such as in text.

And

> normal
>
> Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox)
>   use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's
>   font-family.

As you can see the `line-height` is not necessarily equal to `font-size`

Comment: It's kind of equivalent to having into account the `font-size`, and the border shouldn't count anyway. Maybe part of the "secret" is establishing the `line-height` explicitly.

Comment: @amedina yes because font-size define the line-height but it doesn't make it equal and it will depend in the font-family ... so if you know the line-height you have the good calculation ... check my update, you can use 1em unit to make it more flexible ;)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem a while ago, and was able to solve it through this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29308467/7427111) by using Pseudo element

```css
/* Dirty quick CSS reset */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1;
  background: aliceblue;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 14.2857%;
  /* 100% / 7 */
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.square:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square">1</div>
    <div class="square">2</div>
    <div class="square">3</div>
    <div class="square">4</div>
    <div class="square">5</div>
    <div class="square">6</div>
    <div class="square">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, can you explain why it works?

Comment: Self explanatory, the pseudo element set to 100% padding top which is the same as your width percentage without all the calculation. You could also just put an element in your square if you don't want to use pseudo element

Answer (score 0):

Accounting for the 2px from the border fixed it for me:

`padding-bottom: calc(14.2857% - 18px - 10px);`

```css
/* Dirty quick CSS reset */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1;
  background: aliceblue;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
    
  width: 14.2857%; /* 100% / 7 */
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
  
  /* square-width - font-size - padding-top */
  padding-bottom: calc(14.2857% - 18px - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square">1</div>
    <div class="square">2</div>
    <div class="square">3</div>
    <div class="square">4</div>
    <div class="square">5</div>
    <div class="square">6</div>
    <div class="square">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use snippet, fiddle is old school and your fiddle does not show squares