# Scalable CSS Squares

Tags: css

I'm a little confused with `width`/`height` and working with `flexbox`. I've been trying to get each `div` to be a purple square but it seems to crop to the size of the text. I'd like each colour to maintain a square shape when resized, but just get smaller in scale.

```
.dark-box
{
    background: #8f6cda;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'verdana';
}

.med-box
{
    background: #a68fd8;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'verdana';
}

.light-box
{
    background: #b5a5d7;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'verdana';
}

.dark-box:hover, .med-box:hover, .light-box:hover
{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.dark-box a, .med-box a, .light-box a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'verdana';
}

.col-md-2
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

https://codepen.io/adms2000/pen/wvaaxNz

I'm also unsure why the text only centres when `display: flex` is set as a property in the `tile` class. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css grid of squares with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307971/css-grid-of-squares-with-flexbox)

Comment: Not quite, I just tried it but still seem to be having an issue with the squares cropping to the text. I've edited the code above to fit with the solution you sent across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:before` to style your `flex-items`. Look in snippet.

```css
.col-md-2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

.flex-item {
  /*text-align: center;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'verdana';
  
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.dark-box {
  background: #8f6cda;
}

.med-box {
  background: #a68fd8;
}

.light-box {
  background: #b5a5d7;
}

.flex-item:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.flex-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'verdana';
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="dark-box flex-item">
    <span>Hello</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="med-box flex-item">
    <span>Hello</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="light-box flex-item">
    <span>Hello</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working a bit better. Is there a reason why the squares overlap when resizing? Is it also possible to use a % for the padding?

Comment: @andredms updated answer, use `width` instead of `padding` for `flex-items`

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-text">Hello</div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div class="box-fill box-fill-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-text">Hello</div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div class="box-fill box-fill-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-text">Hello</div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div class="box-fill box-fill-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  position: relative;  
  line-height: 0;     
}

.box-content {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.box-fill {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box-fill-1 {
  background-color: #8f6cda; 
}

.box-fill-2 {
  background-color: #a68fd8;
}

.box-fill-3 {
  background-color: #b5a5d7;
}

.box-text {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Test-Link: https://codepen.io/shervinmr/pen/vYOOzpK