# Square div based on its neighbour

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Base scenario:

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div id="avatar" />
  <div id="info"/>
</div>
```

Assuming `info` will have a dynamic height, based on its content, how can we make `avatar` be always square?

[image: example 1]

In the first example, `info` has 160px height, so `avatar` is a 160x160 square.
In the second example, `info` has more content and its height is 305px, same applies to the `avatar`

Is there a css-only solution?

I was playing with Tailwind: https://play.tailwindcss.com/5ooxVe8F7E, but the green div in this link should have the same height as the red one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css grid of squares with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307971/css-grid-of-squares-with-flexbox)

Comment: `aspect-ratio` is definitely helpful here, @ostone0, but it doesn't supply the whole solution in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. Here's one:

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  padding: 40px;
}

.avatar {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.info {
  background: rgb(170, 108, 108);
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #30353b;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/600/600">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    info<br />
    info<br />
    info<br />
    info<br />
    info<br />
    info
  </div>
</article>
```

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, the demo above only seems to work in Chrome-based browsers (such as Chrome, Edge, Brave). For other browsers, an extra wrapping div is needed:

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
function addPara() {
  const content = document.querySelector('.info');
  content.innerHTML += `<p>Paragraph ${content.childElementCount + 1}</p>`;
}
button.addEventListener("click", addPara, false);
```

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.avatar {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

/* extra styles  */

article {
  margin: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d61be6;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
}

.info {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background: rgb(170, 108, 108);
}

body {
  background: #30353b;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  color: white;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/600/600">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Paragraph 1</p>
      <p>Paragraph 2</p>
      <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="button">Add Text</button>
</article>
```

Click the **Add Text** button to watch what happens as the text grows.

Comment: you can omit the grid-area definitions, they are not needed

Comment: Grid certainly helps here. Something would need to replace it. Just turning it off doesn't work. Grid keeps both columns the same height, which is what this demo relies on.

Comment: I meant you can omit the use of `grid-area` and the code still work since the browser will automatically place the elements for your

Comment: I had to update the demo, as I found the original didn't work in non Chrome-based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

in `display:flex` with `flex-direction:row` the height of your flex items are calculated based on the largest flex-item, so when you apply `height:305px` to `info` , comparing `info` with `avatar` which has `160px` height, info now is taller and larger than the `avatar`, so it applies `305px` height to `avatar` because it is the largest flex-item.

one solution to retrieve `avatar` content `height` is to set its `height` based on `%`, like `height:60%` or `height:100%` (the number doesn't matter and the unit is important) then `avatar` will retrieve its content and original `height`.