# How can I make a div's width be the same as it's height when it's in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a headerbar with the usual content. App-Logo, nav, some controls.

The navbar's height is not set, but determined by its contents. It is a flex container.

Now I want the App-Logo to stretch to the vertical available space and maintain its aspect ratio.

Here is what it should look like:

[image: Navbar Goal]

Here is the code which achieves the image above:

```css
.headerbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.logo {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; /* Not working */

  border-radius: 5px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 0%, rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="headerbar">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <p>Link 1</p>
  <p>Link 2</p>
  <p>Link 3</p>
</div>
```

Link to code: https://jsfiddle.net/v2ta54eg/19/

As you can see, the logo is not visible. It seems to only stretch itself, as expected, but the `aspect-ratio` property has no effect on the width. The width stays 0.

What tried to do, was use `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1` and I expected it to set the width to the same amount as the height. This is because the height is kind of set with `aling-self: stretch`.

So the question is:

How can I make a div have the same width as height, taking the height from the flex parent `align-items: stretch` / `align-self: stretch`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with only css - the only way to get your width matching your height is by using `aspect-ratio`, but then your element will become a replaced element and flex has an issue with them: https://jsfiddle.net/7z5ghLn2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this with a little extra HTML:

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.headerbar {
  display: flex;
  padding: .5rem;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.logo {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 0%, rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 100%);
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="headerbar">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <p>Link 1</p>
      <p>Link 2</p>
      <p>Link 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work! Could you maybe explain a bit why this works?

Comment: Hah, I wish I could. I was trying to do something similar with an image recently, and it worked well without the extra wrapper but only on Chrome-based browsers. Flexbox and Grid do have powers in some circumstances to understand their container height without it being specified, which is why the `height: 100%` can work here, where it wouldn't have in the past. It is odd that your original didn't work, given that the div is stretching full height. Here's that similar example I was talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76904694/square-div-based-on-its-neighbour/76905006#76905006

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The solution you provided works in Chrome and FF

Answer (score 1):

You will have better luck using CSS grid instead

```css
.headerbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* column flow */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr; /* set a height to rows */
  justify-content: start; /* align to left */
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 0%, rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="headerbar">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <p>Link 1</p>
  <p>Link 2</p>
  <p>Link 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work on Firefox btw

Answer (score 0):

Remove withd add these two values to the .logo

```
.logo {
    aspect-ratio: 1/1; /*aspect ratio 1:1 (width/height) */
    flex: 0 0 auto; /* Prevent the logo from growing or shrinking */
}
```

Comment: Okay, the `flex: 0 0 auto;` is interesting. I tried it, but it still doesn't work. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v2ta54eg/19/

Answer (score 0):

`align-items: stretch` is not a height, or any other unit of length. It's just a command that tells flex items to consume available space.

`aspect-ratio` is not working because it doesn't have enough to go on.

If you add height to the container, it will work.

```css
.headerbar {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  height: 150px; /* NEW */
}

.logo {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border-radius:5px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 0%, rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="headerbar">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <p>Link 1</p>
    <p>Link 2</p>
    <p>Link 3</p>
  </div>
</html>
```

OR, if you add width to the items, it will work:

```css
.headerbar {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.logo {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  flex: 0 0 150px; /* modified */
  border-radius:5px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 0%, rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="headerbar">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <p>Link 1</p>
    <p>Link 2</p>
    <p>Link 3</p>
  </div>
</html>
```

But, it won't work with just `width: auto` (i.e., `flex-basis: auto`).

Comment: Thanks for the info. It helped me to better understand why it's not working.