# Gallery with Materialize in CSS position?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a instagram like website I need some help with positioning cards in CSS. Because when ever they are added they get put underneath one and other. I have tried to play with positing in CSS and can't get the perfect fit.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <br>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

           <div class="col s12 m7">
             <div class="card large">
               <div class="card-image">
                 <img src="images/test.jpg">
                 <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
               </div>
               <div class="card-content">
                 <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                 I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
               </div>
               <div class="card-action">
               <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>

         </div>

         <div class="row">

              <div class="col s12 m7">
                <div class="card large">
                  <div class="card-image">
                    <img src="images/test.jpg">
                    <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                    I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-action">
                  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
```

If you look at instagram it has 3 pictures beside each other. I want to do the same but with 2 of them any advice?
[image]

Comment: Just put them next to each other with padding and set a width for the container so that it can only have 2 images next to each other

Comment: @ChrisG it did not work sadly one is bigger then the other.

Comment: I came up with a responsive flexbox grid that would work beautifully for your layout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares/34950995#34950995

Comment: @patrickberkeley Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping each card in a `.row` causes them to be on separate lines. Also, the grid is based on a max of 12 columns, so setting each card to have a 12 column width will cause them to stack. I changed the `s12` to `s6` to get 2 per line. I'm not really sure what the `.m7` class does, so I removed it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6">
      <div class="card large">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="images/test.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s6">
      <div class="card large">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="images/test.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```