# How to make panel height perfect square with panel's 50% width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make 4 perfect squares using [bootstrap panels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels)?

The `width` is correct, but if I set the height to `50%` nothing happens. I don't want to manually set the height with `150px` for example because based upon the screen size the height needs to fluidly grow/shrink in size to match `width`.

[image]

**view**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Basic panel example
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.panel-default {
    border-style: none;
    border: none;
    width: 49.5%;
    height: 49.5%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.panel-body {
    background-color: #446CB3;
    color: white;
    height: 50%;
    padding-top: 19%;
}
```

Comment: This can also be helpfull: [Grid of responsive squares](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20456694/1811992)

Comment: Yea looking into now. Thanks for the suggestions. Struggling tho. Wouldn't call it a duplicate, but I guess close enough @web-tiki

Comment: You can try using 50vw instead of 50% - https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com the "padding technique" is well explained in the dupe. you just need to use 'padding-bottom: 50%;' and position all the content absolutly so it doesn't extedn the containers height like in the grid of responsive squares answer.