# Change position of Images HTML when Window changes

Tags: css, html, image

This is probably much easier than I'm making it sound.

Basically I have 6 Images, each with a button underneath...
This is what it looks like:
[image: Images with Buttons Underneath]

I just place them like this:

```
<img src="Image.png" width="350" height="208" style="margin: 0px 16px">
<img src="Image.png.png" width="350" height="208" style="margin: 0px 16px">
<img src="Button.png" width="282" height="84" style="margin: 0px 16px">
<img src="Button.png" width="282" height="84" style="margin: 0px 16px">
```

It looks great on a typical browser window. But when I make the window narrower, it goes like this:
[image: 2 Images, then 2 Buttons]

Which makes sense give how I list my images/buttons.

But I want them to look like this when the window is narrowed:
[image: Nice and in order]

What can I add to my very basic HTML to keep this in a nice and format no matter how wide the window is?

Ideally I'd like to go from a 2 by `x` grid as max, down to a 1 by `x` grid as seen in the first and final images.

A push in the right direction would be amazing.

I did look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares) on Stackoverflow, but it's far more complex as only works with squares.

I look forward to your help :D

**UPDATE**

https://jsfiddle.net/du6Lu4ge/

looks like this:
[image]

when resized, looks like this:
[image]

:(

Comment: Couldn't you group each red and corresponding blue div in one parent div? So that when the page shrinks, they collapse beneath eachother as a pair instead of independently?

Comment: That sounds exactly how I would like it, but I'm not sure how to implement it :( Thanks for commenting :)

Comment: Can you post your relevant CSS and HTML, or make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Just use flexbox - http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

Comment: @LuisP.A. why use flexbox here?!

Comment: Updated :) Sorry it's basic. The rest is just a header and footer. This all happens in the body. Thank you.

Comment: @Reanimation What about something along the lines of [this](https://jsfiddle.net/du6Lu4ge/2/)?

Comment: @Santi That's perfect. EXACTLY what I'm looking for. Will it work if everything kept central?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/du6Lu4ge/3/

Hope it helps you out!

What I did was to wrap the `image` and the `button` in a div `.img-wrapper` styled with `display: inline-block`

Comment: Credit to both you and @Santi. Thank you so much for posting.
Absolutely perfect. :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

this example is working full responsive, you can simply edit the css and add viewports.

html:

```
<div class="imageContainer">
  <div class="imageBlock">
    <!--<img class="image" src="image.png">-->
    <div class="image">
       your image
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonBlock">
    <!--<img class="button" srck="button.png">-->
    <div class="button">
       your button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="imageContainer">
  <div class="imageBlock">
    <!--<img class="image" src="image.png">-->
    <div class="image">
       your image
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonBlock">
    <!--<img class="button" srck="button.png">-->
    <div class="button">
       your button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="imageContainer">
  <div class="imageBlock">
    <!--<img class="image" src="image.png">-->
    <div class="image">
       your image
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonBlock">
    <!--<img class="button" srck="button.png">-->
    <div class="button">
       your button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="imageContainer">
  <div class="imageBlock">
    <!--<img class="image" src="image.png">-->
    <div class="image">
       your image
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonBlock">
    <!--<img class="button" srck="button.png">-->
    <div class="button">
       your button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.imageContainer {
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block; 
}

.imageContainer .imageBlock {
   display: inline-block;    
}

.imageContainer .imageBlock .image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: darkred;  
}

.imageContainer .buttonBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.imageContainer .buttonBlock .button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px 50px; /* simple way to center it */
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

you can test it on https://jsfiddle.net/q10fbesm/

edit: if you need a 2 line grid, simply put a container arround this html, style it with `max-widht: 801px`;