# How to make a div image responsive

Tags: html, css

I tried with

```css
.slider {
    background: url(../images/slid1.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: cover;
max-width: 100%;
    min-height:800px;
 
}
.slider1 {
    background: url(../images/slid2.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slider2 {
    background: url(../images/slid3.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

i want to know how to make this div image responsive?

Comment: i want to know how to make a div background image in which i use this css code?

Comment: If you apply those classes to block-level elements like `div`'s, it is already responsive. What is the problem - and related code - exactly?

Comment: <div class="slider">
      <div class="carousel-caption kb_caption slider-grid">
       <h3>Great Shakya Muni Buddha</h3>
            <!-- <p>The Best Way To Be Lost.</p> --></div>
     </div>

Comment: i m using it in this way but the background image didn't get responsvie according to screen size...it crops

Comment: So? Responsive and cropping are not mutually exclusive. It's still responsive.

Comment: but i want complete image after changing the screen size

Comment: it is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grid of responsive squares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares)

Comment: sorry i m not geeting u...could u please elaborate it?

Comment: @sunit shakya: it's already responsive.

Comment: but it is still not showingg complete image why??

Comment: @sunitshakya: Because slder class has min-height:800px; and while browser resizing this class height is constant and element (that has slider class) not resizing according to image proportion. That's why you are not able to see full image on every resolution.

Answer (score -1):

In your example css you are using `background-size:cover`. This property causes the image to scale to the smallest size in where both the width and height of the image are at least the size of the container. `background-size:contain` might be give the behaviour you want. It is the opposite of cover, in that it tries to scale the image to be as big as possible in the allocated space without clipping.

```css
.img
{
  background-image:url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  min-height:400px;
  max-width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
</div>
```