# Drawing a 2x2 grid using bootstrap

Tags: css

I'm trying to draw a 2x2 grid using bootstrap. My aim is to make a grid which looks similar to this:

[image: Grid]

with an onclick event handler on each tile. I'm having trouble setting the height of the tiles though and have something like this so far...

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
     <div class ="col-md-2">
         one
      </div>
     <div class ="col-md-2">
        two
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class ="col-md-2">
         three
      </div>
     <div class ="col-md-2">
        four
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: add one more class to set height

Comment: Notice that `col-*-2` is a one-sixth and not a half column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grid of responsive squares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares)

Comment: BTW if you still can't figure it out here is your answer:
http://codepen.io/rema/pen/Lxbyyp

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap columns should total to 12. The code:

```
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```