# How do I account for the white space in-between images with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, width

I am trying to scale my images using width in CSS so that my images will be responsive. I would like to have 3 images across the screen up to a certain max-width, but the white space in between them knocks one down after setting width to 33.3%. I'd still like the small white space between the images, but I want the images to span across 100% of the width of it's container. How do I fix this issue?

```
img{
    width:33.3%;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ErNeT/1736/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grid of responsive squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ensure that all HTML elements have the box-sizing property set to border-box. This makes sure that the padding and border are included in the total width and height of the elements.[source](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp)

```
img{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid transparent;//keep your little margins by transparent borders 5px wide
}
```

You can change how much gap do you want between them by changing 5px into another width.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `font-size: 0;` on the container to remove the whitespace, and if you only need to support back to IE9 you can use `calc()` to calculate the width with the margin. OR you could use flexbox if you only need to support modern browsers!

Examples of both here:
http://jsfiddle.net/s3cmnpo3/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
img{
    width:33.3%;
    float: left;
}
```