# Getting rows of equal height in nested columns HTML Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, flask, twitter-bootstrap-3, jinja2

I am building a Flask app and I am having some troubles with one of the HTML-templates. What I want to do is a sort of 3x3 tile layout for news stories, all tiles of equal height and width. This is my html code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}

<div class = "col-lg-12 row.row-eq-height text-left">
    <div class = "col-lg-4">
      {% for result in results[:3] %}
        {% include '_result.html' %}
      {%endfor %}
      </div>
    <div class = "col-lg-4">
      {% for result in results[3:6] %}
        {% include '_result.html' %}
      {%endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class = "col-lg-4">
      {% for result in results[6:9] %}
        {% include '_result.html' %}
      {%endfor %}
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that I am getting three nice and evenly sized columns, but the rows are not of equal height. My guess is that it has to do with the nested columns (having col-lg-12 and then col-lg-4). Is there any way to get all the rows the same height?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a few bugs in your markup:

1. `row.row-eq-height` should be `row row-eq-height` (no period (`.`) and a space  between the classnames.
2. Bootstrap doesn't allow a `col` and `row` to be in the same `<div>`. You should be able to remove the `col-lg-12` from your first `<div>`.
3. It looks like you have too many closing divs `</div>`.

Final code would be:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height text-left">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    {% for result in results[:3] %}
      {% include '_result.html' %}
    {%endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    {% for result in results[3:6] %}
      {% include '_result.html' %}
    {%endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    {% for result in results[6:9] %}
      {% include '_result.html' %}
    {%endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

**More info:**
Be sure to checkout [Bootstrap's grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for more info on how to structure your markup, but generally it would be `container` > `row` > `col`.

**Keep in mind:** `row-eq-height` is taking advantage of flexbox which [does not work in IE9](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and below.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I am new to html/bootstrap, hence the bugs in the markup. However, even after following your suggestions I still get the same picture: Equal columns, but no equal height rows...I really don't know why it is not working...

Comment: @user5791200 can you post a link? Also do you know what version of Bootstrap you are using?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3. I now found a solution working for me by not using bootstrap but I found another solution by following the steps outlined in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares . I just could not get it to work with bootstrap... And I do not have a link yet as the app is not online yet, still in debugging...

Comment: It's possible that you don't have the `.row-eq-height` class in your styles. You can try and add the class `.row-eq-height { display: flex }` to your css.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, I found a solution not involving bootstrap here: stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares - but if anyone still has an all-bootstrap solution it would certainly be interesting! I still have no clue why it did not work..