# Ionic grid of squares containing mix of portrait and landscape images

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

Using Ionic 4 I'm trying to create a 3x3 grid of squares, where each square contains an image. The images have different sizes and orientations (portrait / landscape) but the squares shall have an aspect ratio of 1:1.

Simply adding the images to rows and columns, for example like this:

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col><img src="landscape.jpg"></ion-col>
    <ion-col><img src="portrait.jpg"></ion-col>
    <ion-col><img src="landscape.jpg"></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col><img src="landscape.jpg"></ion-col>
    <ion-col><img src="landscape.jpg"></ion-col>
    <ion-col><img src="landscape.jpg"></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col><img src="portrait.jpg"></ion-col>
    <ion-col><img src="portrait.jpg"></ion-col>
    <ion-col><img src="portrait.jpg"></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

gives the following layout:
[Images added to rows and columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJRJd.png)

which is not what I want since the grid squares have varying aspect ratios.
What I'm trying to accomplish is this layout:
[Preferred layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbeZS.png)

The preferred answer to the following SO question comes close:
[Grid of responsive squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares)

This solution works for squares containing landscape images. For example, the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="square">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <img src="landscape.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.square {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

gives the following layout: [Square containing landscape image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYt8m.png)

But when the square contains a portrait image the result is this:
[Square containing portrait image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz4NK.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

---

UPDATE:
The answer of 'brianspinosa' works if I set the "background-repeat" property to "no-repeat" and the "background-position" property to "center".

For example, the following code:

```css
.square {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <div class="square" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/640x480)">
      </div>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <div class="square" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/342x480)">
      </div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

gives the following correct layout: [Correct layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhMsm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is achieve what the "background-size" property does for background images. You could update your markup to set the images as background images and then set the "background-size" property to "contain".

The other thing you could do is use the [object-fit property on your images, though there is no IE support for it](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit).

Comment: Many thanks, your solution works (see the update of my question).

Comment: Awesome! If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it as correct. If there is still something off, let me know.