# How to define size of divs with thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf, html-lists, image-size, video-thumbnails

I have a div with a list of divs inside which carry images and videos. I need them to be all the same size (a square with the same size would be good). Cause now it's all misaligned

That's what I have tried till now:

```
<div class="row text-center text-lg-left">
                        <div th:each="inst, iStat : ${instances}" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6"
                            th:if="${inst.fileStatus} eq ${T(br.com.macrosul.stetho.entity.FileStatus).UPLOADED}">
                            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" data-target="#showMedia" data-toggle="modal" th:data-slide-to="${iStat.index}"
                                    style="width: 100%;" th:src="@{'/instances/' + ${inst.id} + '/thumbnail' + ${folder != null ? '?folder=' + folder.id : ''}}" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This space will support probably 5 images and that's how it looks like currently:
[image: current behavior]

The middle one is a video.

I also would need something to distinguish between video and photos, how could I indicate it's a video? Is that possible to attach a "play button" in front of it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a CSS question, than a Thymeleaf question. But here is one approach which may help you.

The approach is inspired by details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares/20457076#20457076).

The following Thymeleaf template assumes you want to display five identially-sized squares in a row, with an image (or video) in each square:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Grid Demo</title>

        <style>

            <!-- included just for reference 
            div.three {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                width: 29%;
                padding-bottom: 29%;
                margin: 1.7%;
                border: 1px solid grey;
            }
            div.four {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                width: 22%;
                padding-bottom: 22%;
                margin: 1%;
                border: 1px solid grey;
            }
            -->

            <!-- five squares in a horizontal row -->
            div.five {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                width: 17%;
                padding-bottom: 17%;
                margin: 1.1%;
                border: 1px solid grey;
            }

            div.content {
                position: absolute;
                height: 80%;
                width: 90%;
                padding: 10% 5%;
            }

            div.table {
                display: table;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            div.table-cell {
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            .content .rs {
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                max-height: 90%;
                max-width: 100%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div th:each="inst, iStat : ${instances}" class="five">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <img class="rs" th:attr="src=${inst}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

In my case, the end result looks like this, across the width of my browser screen:

[image: Five squares]

Points to note:

1) If you want to dynamically display 3, 4, or 5 boxes, then you can parameterize the `class="five"` attribute in the Thymeleaf template. The [size](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#lists) of the `${instances}` object will tell you which class you need:

```
${#lists.size(instances)}
```

2) If you want to add video controls in a square, that would involve passing an object to Thymeleaf which contains not only the media file name, but a boolean (or similar) to indicate if the media is playable. Add such content in its own `<div>`, following the relevant `<img>` tag:

```
<div th:if="${isVideo}">...</div>
```

I hope that gives you some ideas.